# Regular expressions to remove all characters except alphanumerics and certain punctuation

Tags: php, regex

I use this for clean a string:

```
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_.;|+ -]/", '', $str);
```

Works good, but I need add into the regex the char '&' too, I tried to add:

```
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_.;&|+ -]/", '', $str);
```

or

```
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_.;\&|+ -]/", '', $str);
```

but this doesn't work, why?
How can I do it? 
Big thanks.

Comment: It works for me. `preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_.;&|+ -]/", '', '&')` returns exactly `&` as expected.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: also, what string do you use to test your regex? You should post your starting string and your expected result, so that we can check if our solutions are consistent with what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

i tried your pattern `$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_.;\&|+ -]/", '', $str);` it seems to be working fine for me even without escaping it...

try this tool to test your regular expressions
[Regular expression tester](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/)

Comment: @holub backslash the backslash thingy dones work in php (atleast) what it will do is escape a backslash("\") not "&"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about php, but you can try to backslash the backslash:  `\\&`

Answer (score 0):

`[&]` should be enough, see

http://www.regexp.net/?function=preg_match&pattern=[%26]&string=Batman+%26+Robin

Comment: I do it, added [&] but doesn't work :/ 
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_.;[&]|+ -]/", '', $str);

Comment: You're already inside of `[]`, I meant your second alternative (in your question) should be fine.